# Solving Cahn-Hilliard equation: LinearSolve: Linear equation encountered that has no solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, finite-element-method

I have built the Cahn-Hilliard Eqs. in MMA (Mixed Formulation, second order), However, it doesnot work in MMA using Finite Element.

**LinearSolve: Linear equation encountered that has no solution.**

**And** **"... are not the same shape"**.

Theory & numerical formulation based on this [**FEniCS Benchmark Test**](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html#)

***My code***:

```
(*Initial Parameters*)Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Mobi = 1.0; lame = 0.01; noise = 0.02; conu0 = 0.63;
xmax = 1.0;
ymax = 1.0;
tmax = 1.0;

Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1};
RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000, "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement];
mesh["Wireframe"]
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]]
u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, conu0 + noise*(0.5 - RandomReal[{0, 1}, n])];
Plot3D[u0[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh]

op1 = D[u[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[v[t, x, y], {x, y}] Mobi

op2 = v[t, x, y] - 200 u[t, x, y] (1 - 3 u[t, x, y] + 2 u[t, x, y]^2) + 
      lame Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}]

{unn, vnn} = 
  NDSolve[{op1 == 0, op2 == 0, u[0, x, y] == u0[x, y], 
    v[0, x, y] == 0}, {u, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
```

Comment: It runs probably only in MMA 12 because @user21 added support for nonlinear FEM only by then.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher , I have defined  initial conditions for v

Comment: Oh, I've just realized that Cahn-Hilliard is not parabolic in `v`. So we have a mixture of a parabolic equation in `u` and an elliptic equation in `v` (but the equation for `v` has always be solve for a current, fixed `t`, only`. I am afraid that @user21 did not anticipate such a use case. I think one can solve the equation with the low-level FEM functionalities...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher therefore we got the error:"... are not the same shape". ? Can we solve this Fenics Benchmark using MMA?

Comment: Is FEM necessary for you? If not, check this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125734/1871

Comment: @xzczd I only want to use Finite element and mixed formulation in MMA

Comment: @xzczd you may see this problem:https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html#

Comment: Then the problem is troublesome, because 2nd equation in the mixed formulation doesn't involve derivative of `t`, and `NDSolve` simply can't handle this type of system well, at least now, AFAIK. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163923/1871

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can offer an easy-to-implement explicit method of Euler using `FEM` and `NDSolve`. Here we used a test example like on Python from https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html#. The output picture is about the same. These are the initial data, equations, and parameters.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
Lx = 1; Ly = 1; nn = 50; t0 = 5*10^-6;
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

f[x_] := 100 x^2 (1 - x)^2
lambd = 1/100; noise = 0.02; conu0 = 0.63;
M = 1;
thet = 1/2;
eq1 = D[c[t, x, y], t] - Div[M Grad[u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0;
eq2 = u[t, x, y] - D[f[c[t, x, y]], c[t, x, y]] + 
    lambd Laplacian[c[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000, 
      "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement];
mesh["Wireframe"]
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
      conu0 + noise*(0.5 - RandomReal[{0, 1}, n])];
uf[0][x_, y_] := 0
cf[0][x_, y_] := u0[x, y]
Plot3D[u0[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

This is the implementation of the explicit Euler.

```
eq = {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + (c[x, y] - cf[i - 1][x, y])/t0 == 
   NeumannValue[0, True], -200 (1 - cf[i - 1][x, y])^2 c[x, y] + 
    200 (1 - c[x, y]) cf[i - 1][x, y]^2 + u[x, y] + 
    1/100 Laplacian[c[x, y], {x, y}] == 
   NeumannValue[0, True]}; Do[{cf[i], uf[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[eq, {c, u}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh] // Quiet;, {i, 1, 
  nn}]
```

This is an animation and 3D image.

```
frame = Table[
   DensityPlot[cf[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", i t0 1.}]], {i, 0, nn, 2}];

ListAnimate[frame]
Plot3D[cf[50][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

I managed to debug code  @Henrik Schumacher, so that with equal parameters and the same input data, similar results are obtained with code above and with code @Henrik Schumacher. Thus, code @Henrik Schumacher passed the test for Python.

Henrik Schumacher debugged code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Mobi = 1.0; lame = 0.01; noise = 0.02; conu0 = 0.63;
xmax = 1.0;
ymax = 1.0;
tmax = 1.0;
a = 1.;
b = 1.;

\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/5000, 
  "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement, "MeshOrder" -> 1]

ClearAll[x, y, u];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {mesh}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}}, 
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, {{DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True]}}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];

(*Discretization*)
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
{load, A, damping, M} = dpde["All"];
(*DeployBoundaryConditions[{load,A},dbc];*)
(*DeployBoundaryConditions[{load,M},dbc];*)
\[Theta] = 1;
\[Tau] = 0.000005;
\[Mu] = Mobi;
\[Lambda] = lame;
L = ArrayFlatten[{{M, \[Tau] \[Mu] \[Theta] A}, {-\[Lambda] A, M}}];
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
m = 50;
f = x \[Function] 100. x^2 (1. - x^2);
Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[f'[x]];
rhs[u_, v_] := 
  Join[M.u - (\[Mu] \[Tau] (1. - \[Theta])) A.v, 
   M.(200 (1 - u)^2 u - 200 (1 - u) u^2)];
S = LinearSolve[L, Method -> "Pardiso"];

u0 = conu0 + noise*(0.5 - RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]);
ulist = ConstantArray[0., {m, n}];
ulist[[1]] = u = u0;

v0 = 0. rhs[u0, 0. u0][[n + 1 ;; 2 n]];
v = v0;
Do[sol = S[rhs[u, v]];
  ulist[[k]] = u = sol[[1 ;; n]];
  v = sol[[n + 1 ;; 2 n]];, {k, 2, m}];
frames = Table[
   Image[Map[ColorData["Rainbow"], 
     Partition[ulist[[k]], Sqrt[n]], {2}], Magnification -> 3], {k, 1,
     m, 1}];
Manipulate[frames[[k]], {k, 1, Length[frames], 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {k}]
```

My code (for comparison):

```
u0i = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
      u0];
uf[0][x_, y_] := 0
cf[0][x_, y_] := u0i[x, y]
DensityPlot[u0i[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
nn = 50; t0 = 
 5*10^-6; eq = {-Laplacian[
      u1[x, y], {x, y}] + (c[x, y] - cf[i - 1][x, y])/t0 == 
   NeumannValue[0, True], -200 (1 - cf[i - 1][x, y])^2 c[x, y] + 
    200 (1 - c[x, y]) cf[i - 1][x, y]^2 + u1[x, y] + 
    1/100 Laplacian[c[x, y], {x, y}] == 
   NeumannValue[0, True]}; Do[{cf[i], uf[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[eq, {c, u1}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh] // Quiet;, {i, 1,
   nn}]

frame = Table[
   DensityPlot[cf[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", i t0 1.}]], {i, 0, nn, 1}];

ListAnimate[frame]
```

Comparison of two results

```
ul = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
     ulist[[nn]]]; {Plot3D[ul[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Theta] = ", \[Theta]}]], 
 Plot3D[cf[nn][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None]}
```

[image: Figure 2]
For $\theta=\frac {1}{2}$ matching is better
[image: Figure 3]

Another method using `NDSolveValue` and `"MethodOfLines"`. The code is very slow and with a warning `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` The result does not match Python and FEM.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
Lx = 1; Ly = 1; nn = 50; t0 = 5*10^-6; tmax = t0 nn;
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

f[x_] := 100 x^2 (1 - x)^2
lambd = 1/100; noise = 0.02; conu0 = 0.63;
M = 1;
thet = 1/2;
eq1 = D[c[t, x, y], t] - Div[M Grad[u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0;
eq2 = u[t, x, y] - D[f[c[t, x, y]], c[t, x, y]] + 
    lambd Laplacian[c[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000, 
      "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement];
mesh["Wireframe"]
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
      conu0 + noise*(0.5 - RandomReal[{0, 1}, n])];
ic = {c[0, x, y] == u0[x, y], u[0, x, y] == 0};
bc = {Derivative[0, 1, 0][c][t, 0, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][c][t, 1, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 0, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 1, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][t, x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][t, x, 1] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 1] == 0};

Monitor[{csol, usol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, ic, bc}, {c, u}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 
    0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
     "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 41, "MaxPoints" -> 81, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = 
      Row[{"t=", CForm[t], " csol=", CForm[c[t, .5, .5]]}])], monitor]
```

Compare the result with FEM (my code)

```
uf[0][x_, y_] := 0
cf[0][x_, y_] := u0[x, y]

eq = {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + (c[x, y] - cf[i - 1][x, y])/t0 == 
   NeumannValue[0, True], -200 (1 - cf[i - 1][x, y])^2 c[x, y] + 
    200 (1 - c[x, y]) cf[i - 1][x, y]^2 + u[x, y] + 
    1/100 Laplacian[c[x, y], {x, y}] == 
   NeumannValue[0, True]}; Do[{cf[i], uf[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[eq, {c, u}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh] // Quiet;, {i, 1, 
  nn}]
{Plot3D[csol[tmax, x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
 Plot3D[cf[50][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}
```

On the left fig. 4 the `"MethodOfLines"`, on the right FEM. It can be seen that in the `"MethodOfLines" high-frequency harmonics are added.
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: many thanks for your support! May I ask a question, is it possible that we can use the semi-implicit method?

Comment: Yes, this is also a way to do it (+1). Anyways, avoiding `InterpolatingFunction`s as I did in my post is _300 times faster_ per iteration when computed on the same mesh...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM We can implement any computational algorithm. But I usually use only explicit Euler, since this method has proved itself well in combination with `FEM` and `NDSolve`. The new algorithm implemented in version 12 did not pass the test in the simplest problem of the flow around a cylinder. And the explicit Euler passed the tests see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I agree and use your method where possible (+1 for solving this problem). But in nonlinear problems I prefer explicit Euler in combination with `FEM` and `NDSolve` because this method has passed tests. I will test your method on a flow past a cylinder.

Comment: Okay, I have to confess: I read "explicit method of Euler " for "explicit Euler method". What you use is _not_ the explicit Euler method; it is mostly implicit Euler with the nonlinearity treated semi-implicitly (in a way that I don't understand).  Speaking of that: The system that you submit to `NDSolve` is nonlinear anyways. Why don't you submit the fully nonlinear equation `-200 (1 - c[x, y])^2 c[x, y] + 200 (1 - c[x, y]) c[x, y]^2 + 
  u[x, y] + 1/100 Laplacian[c[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[0, True]` then?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Of course, this method is explicitly Euler. But iteration on nonlinearity is used. At each step, a linear system of equations is solved with coefficients calculated at the previous step. The scheme looks like this `x=x+t0 f[x]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev As OP, in addition,  I may ask, can we directly solve 4th-order problem (CHs) in MMA, NOT using mixed formulation, e.g. meshless, IgA, etc...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I guess we can solve it using the pseudospectral method.

Comment: @AlexTrounev and can we use  "pseudospectral method" for solid mechanics problem in MMA? Also thanks for your reply!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM We need to discuss this in detail, for example, non-linear oscillations of a beam is a typical problem for spectral and pseudospectral methods.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  e.g. can we use MMA spectral element for this benchmark test? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202955/mma-12-transient-plane-stress-problem/202964?noredirect=1#comment524556_202964

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Is there published data on this mathematical problem?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  it looks like a tensile/shear  test (ASTM)

Comment: @AlexTrounev in other words, can we use mma spectral elements for simple shape (plate/beam) linear elastic problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96878/discussion-between-alex-trounev-and-abcdemmm).

Answer (score 14):

Okay, I don't think that the `NDSolve` interface is currently able to handle the Cahn-Hilliard equations. But the low-level FEM tools can. This is how I set this up.

First, we discretize the geometry and let *Mathematica* return us the `mass` matrix `M` and the stiffness matrix `A`.

```
(*InitialParameters*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Mobi = 1.0; lame = 0.01; noise = 0.02; conu0 = 0.63;
xmax = 1.0;
ymax = 1.0;
tmax = 1.0;
a = 1.;
b = 1.;

Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω,
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> {1 -> 0.005},
   "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement,
   "MeshOrder" -> 1
   ];

ClearAll[x, y, u];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {mesh}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}},
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}
   ];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {{DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True]}}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];

(*Discretization*)
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
{load, A, damping, M} = dpde["All"];
(*DeployBoundaryConditions[{load,A},dbc];*)
(*DeployBoundaryConditions[{load,M},dbc];*)
```

From the [source](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html) provided by OP, I deduce that linear system for each iteration to solve $u_{k+1}$ and $v_{k+1}$ from information on $u_k$ and $v_k$ should be set up as follows:

```
θ = 0.5;
τ = 0.000000001;
μ = Mobi;
λ = lame;
L = ArrayFlatten[{
    {M, τ μ θ A},
    {-λ A, M}
    }];
f = x \[Function] 100. ((1. - x^2)^2);
Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[f'[x]];
rhs[u_, v_] := Join[M.u -  (μ τ (1. - θ)) A.v, M.Df[u]];
S = LinearSolve[L, Method -> "Pardiso"];
```

Setting up an array `ulist` into which to collect the results and random initial conditions

```
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
m = 10000;

u0 = 2. RandomInteger[{0, 1}, n] - 1.;
ulist = ConstantArray[0., {m, n}];
ulist[[1]] = u = u0;

v0 = rhs[u0, 0. u0][[n + 1 ;; 2 n]];
v = v0;
```

The actual numerical solve of the pde:

```
Do[
  sol = S[rhs[u, v]];
  ulist[[k]] = u = sol[[1 ;; n]];
  v = sol[[n + 1 ;; 2 n]];
  , {k, 2, m}];
```

Visualization of the phase field:

```
frames = Table[
   Image[
    Map[
     ColorData["ThermometerColors"],
     Partition[0.5 (Clip[ulist[[k]], {-1., 1.}] + 1.), Sqrt[n]],
     {2}
     ]
    ],
   {k, 1, m, 25}
   ];
Manipulate[
 frames[[k]],
 {k, 1, Length[frames], 1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {k}
 ]
```

[image]

I am not entirely sure, but I think I managed to implement the Neumann boundary conditions correctly.

## Edit

Fixed the former version. For the generation of initial data, I assumed that the relevant phase values (the minima of the phase field potential) lied at `-1` and `+1` while the forcing term was implemented for `0` and `+1`. I fixed it such that `-1` and `+1` are the two minima. Now the results look really like Cahn-Hillard flow.

## Edit 2

I realized only by now that the solver in the FEniCS example really solves the nonlinear system

$$
  \begin{aligned}
\int_\varOmega u_{n+1} \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d} x 
+
\tau \, \int_\varOmega \langle \nabla (\theta \, v_{n+1} + (1 - \theta) \, v_{n}) ,\nabla \varphi \rangle \, \mathrm{d} x 
&= 0
&\text{for all $\varphi \in H^1(\varOmega)$,}
\\
\int_\varOmega v_{n+1} \, \psi \, \mathrm{d} x
-
\int_\varOmega f'(v_{n+1}) \, \psi \, \mathrm{d} x
-
\lambda
\int_\varOmega \langle \nabla v_{n} ,\nabla \psi \rangle \,\mathrm{d} x 
&=0
&\text{for all $\psi \in H^1(\varOmega)$,}
  \end{aligned}
$$
while I was somewhat lazy used the following as a replacement for the second equation:
$$
  \begin{aligned}
\int_\varOmega v_{n+1} \, \psi \, \mathrm{d} x
-
\int_\varOmega f'(v_{n}) \, \psi \, \mathrm{d} x
-
\lambda
\int_\varOmega \langle \nabla v_{n} ,\nabla \psi \rangle \,\mathrm{d} x 
&=0
&\text{for all $\psi \in H^1(\varOmega)$.}
  \end{aligned}
$$
This is probably the reason why this method requires so small step sizes. The reason however why I did so is because a nonlinear solve (e.g., with Newton's method) in each iteration slows down the computations considerably,
because the system with matrix similar to `L` would have to be solved several times per iteration. Moreover, the system matrix `L` would change over time which is very expensive when a direct linear solver is employed.

One could probably mend this a bit by using the linearization
$$
  \begin{aligned}
\int_\varOmega v_{n+1} \, \psi \, \mathrm{d} x
-
\int_\varOmega (f'(v_{n}) \, + f''(v_{n}) \, (v_{n+1}-v_{n})) \,\psi \, \mathrm{d} x
-
\lambda
\int_\varOmega \langle \nabla v_{n} ,\nabla \psi \rangle \,\mathrm{d} x 
&=0
&\text{for all $\psi \in H^1(\varOmega)$.}
  \end{aligned}
$$
However, this would still imply that the system matrix `L` changes in each iteration. So when a direct linear solver like `LinearSolve` with options `Method- > "Multifrontal"` or `Method- > "Pardiso"` is employed, this will become much more expensive. In principle, also `NDSolve` can solve this system (Alex Trounev uses a similar technique). With an iterative linear solver, this change of system matrix might come considerably less expensive; I am not sure. Unfortunately, I have no time to try.

Comment: in this case, can we apply  PeriodicBoundaryCondition for the low-level FE Tool, i.e: left equal to right; top equal to bottom?

Comment: pbc1 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t,x, y], x == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1, 
   TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]];      pbc2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t,x, y], y == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]];  ?

Comment: Is that a question? I don't get it.

Comment: @Henrick Schumacher If we use the method you proposed, namely low-level fem, can we also use Periodic boundary condition here?

Comment: Yes, should be possible by adjusting mass and stiffness matrox. Maybe this can be done bu assigning the desired boundary conditions in `bcdata` and by applyingcalling `DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, A}, dbc];` and `DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, M}, dbc];` before constructing `L`. But I don't have the time to test that at the moment.

Comment: the result looks like Allen Cahn process, not Cahn Hilliard ....

Comment: in this case, we need damping matrix, not mass matrix??

Comment: (+1) not sure I mentioned this before, in case I have not, you can save yourself some typing by using `{dpde2, dbc2, vd2, sd2, md2} = 
  ProcessPDEEquations[{D[u[t, x, y], t] - 
      Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0, u[0, x, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
(*dpde["SystemMatrices"]\[Equal]dpde2["SystemMatrices"][[{1,2,4,3}]]*)` The ordering is different because `NDSolve` constructs a damping matrix while you set it up with a mass matrix.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Your code does not pass the test for Python. There we need 50 steps with $\tau =5*10^{-6}. In this case, your code gives an error.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Hm. This is a _nonlinear_ parabolic PDE, so Crank-Nicolson is probably not unconditionally stable. That means that the step size has to be decreased with the mesh size; otherwise, instabilities arise that lead to numerical overflow. But probably the step size has to be reduced less drastically with Crank-Nicolson scheme as with explicit Euler scheme. Cahn-Hilliard is a parabolic 4-th-order PDE in disguise. So the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy condition should require something like $\tau \in O(h^4)$(!!!) for a stable explicit Euler scheme.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Actually, my code uses the $\theta$-method. So you can obtain explicit Euler with $\theta = 0$, Crank-Nicolson with $\theta = \frac{1}{2}$, and implicit Euler with $\theta = 1$. In fact, Crank-Nicolson is a bit notorious for its high oscillations which, in a lonlinear setting, may be amplified instead of being reduced. So I expect `θ = 1.` to be much more robust, alas, requiring again smaller step sizes (as implicit Euler is not unconditionally stable even for linear PDE).

Comment: @AlexTrounev When I meant that my code is more efficient is that it avoids the construction and evaluations of any `InterpolatingFunction`s. This technique is entirely independent of the time integration scheme. So I don't argue for or against a particular integration scheme. This is actually also not the right place to do it. I simply wanted to point out how to implement these time integration schemes _efficiently_ in _Mathematica_. And a factor of 300 for the runtime per time integration step schoud not be neglected.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher OK! I ran the required test with $t =50*5*10^{-6}$ in 25000 steps with $\tau =10^{-8}$. It takes a very long time and takes all the memory. But I did not get the expected picture.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I managed to debug your code and pass the Python test. See update to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev The only difference that I see in the debugged code is that you replaced $f(x) = 100 ((1 - x^2)^2)$ by  $f(x) = 100 x^2 (1 - x)^2$. I'd like to point out that I _said_ in my post that I did that on purpose because I wanted the two phases to lie at $\pm 1$.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In addition, I changed the time step, grid, and initial data, modified `frames` and did a lot of different calculations until I found it all ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher +1: ,)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The best agreement between the two methods is obtained with $\theta =\frac {1}{2}$. If $\theta =0$ (explicit Euler), the test fails (with your code). Perhaps you are right that my method is not a very explicit Euler.