# How to solve Coupled a Parabolic and Elliptic PDE in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, fourier-analysis, finite-difference-method

I want to solve a mixed PDE Parabolic-Elliptic system in 3-dimension (rectangular coordinate), as shown below:
[image]

The respective code version with parameters value, boundary and initial conditions is,

```
    L = 1000;(*length of cube*) 
    pts = 200; 
    T = 400;(*Time integration*) 
    ϵ = 50 λ; 
    s = 2.75; 
    δ = 2.76; 
    γ = 2.75; 
    τ = 3.65; 
    χ = 1.10; 
    A = 1.6438; 
    μ = 0.2; 
    θ = 1; 
    λ = 50;
    
    (*system of nonlinear PDE*) 

    pde = {0 == ϵ Laplacian[σ[t,x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + s - δ ϕ[t, x, y, z] - γ σ[t,x, y, z], D[ϕ[t, x, y, z],t] == λ Laplacian[ϕ[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 64/τ (1 - ϕ[t, x, y, z]) (ϕ[t, x, y, z] - 1/2) + χ σ[t,x, y, z] ϕ[t, x, y, z] - Aϕ[t, x, y, z] - 3 μ θ^2 (2 θ - 3) ϕ[t, x, y, z] (ϕ[t, x, y, z] - 1)}; 

    (*Periodic boundary condition*) 
    
    bc = {ϕ[t, 0, y, z] == ϕ[t, L, y, z], ϕ[t, x, 0, z] == ϕ[t, x, L, z], ϕ[t, x, y, 0] == ϕ[t, x, y,L], σ[t, 0, y, z] == σ[t, L, y, z], σ[t, x, 0, z] == σ[t, x, L, z], σ[t, x, y, 0] == σ[t, x, y, L]}; 

(*initial condition*) 

ic = {ϕ[0, x, y, z] == If[(x - 500)^2 + (y - 500)^2 + (z - 500)^2 <= (25)^2, 1, 0]}; 

eqns = Flatten@{pde, bc, ic}; 

(*Integration*)

sol = NDSolve[eqns, {ϕ, σ}, {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {z, 0, L}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> pts, "MaxPoints" -> pts}}];
```

but something is not working well.

> NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one
> independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one
> value of the other independent variable.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First equation is unclear formulated. Do you suppose that $\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}=0$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev , it is assumed the $\sigma$ to be in a stationary state in the time scale.

Comment: Ok, I understand that you try to solve `pde` in a cube. But why do you set `L=1000` with `pts=200`?   Is it real problem or you just test `NDSolve`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, it is a real problem of mathematical modelling.

Comment: It looks like  the Cahn-Hilliard model discussed on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202446/solving-cahn-hilliard-equation-linearsolve-linear-equation-encountered-that-ha

Answer (score 2):

You can not solve mixed time dependent and stationary equations. You'd have to make the first equation time dependent. Something like this starts to time integrate, though I did not wait for it to finish:

```
pde = {D[σ[t, x, y, z], t] == ϵ Laplacian[σ[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 
     s - δ ϕ[t, x, y, z] - γ σ[t, x, y, z], 
   D[ϕ[t, x, y, z], t] == λ Laplacian[ϕ[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 
     64/τ (1 - ϕ[t, x, y, z]) (ϕ[t, x, y, z] - 
        1/2) + χ σ[t, x, y, z] ϕ[t, x, y, z] - A ϕ[t, x, y, z] - 
     3 μ θ^2 (2 θ - 3) ϕ[t, x, y, z] (ϕ[t, x, y, z] - 1)};

ic = {σ[0, x, y, z] == 0, ϕ[0, x, y, z] == 
    If[(x - 500)^2 + (y - 500)^2 + (z - 500)^2 <= (25)^2, 1, 0]};
```

Comment: @Nasser, thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to integrate the equations as they are and it takes a long time. Does anyone have any idea how to optimize integration time? Could the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) decrease simulation time?