# How to speed up this small 2D graphics code?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, generative-art, rendering, performance

The following code is very slow, with Mathematica 13.2 on a Mac Silicon M2 Pro:

```
domains = 1500; (* Number of domains in 3D *)

randomDomains = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomInteger[{1, 2}]}, {n, 1, Ndomains}];

ImageDomaines = MedianFilter[
    ImageAdjust[ListDensityPlot[randomDomains,
    InterpolationOrder -> 0,
    Frame -> False,
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}], 0],
8]
```

Why is it so slow?  How can we speed it up, and get curved random patterns?

Here's a preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

Comment: Why do you make *three*-dimensional domains if you're only interested in a *two*-dimensional image?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, it's just the simplest way I found to make a random pattern like this.

Comment: Try it in TWO D.

Comment: `ListContourPlot[RandomReal[1, {35, 35}], InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 Contours -> 1, ContourShading -> {Red, Purple}, Frame -> False]` could be a starting point.

Comment: @Syed, it works, but the result isn't as good.  There are some artifacts (rude edges, some apparent vertical strikes or other artifacts).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  It is impossible to draw such 2D image without any extra data(for example 3D data) or extra restrict function( for example a distance function define on 2D)

Comment: You're turning your data first into a plot, then an image and then do a MedianFilter over that. That's a rather inefficient way to do things.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, then how would you suggest to get the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, `InterpolationOrder->0` should use Voronoi cells. So you can do it this way:

```
Ndomains = 1500;
x = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Ndomains, 2}];
cols = RandomChoice[
   {
    Directive[FaceForm[ColorData["Rainbow"][0]], EdgeForm[]], 
    Directive[FaceForm[ColorData["Rainbow"][1]], EdgeForm[]]
    },
   1500
   ];
M = VoronoiMesh[x, 
  MeshCellStyle -> Thread[Thread[{2, Range[Ndomains]}] -> cols], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
img = MedianFilter[Rasterize[M, ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}], 6]
```

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't give the same kind of output.  It's not similar to the example I gave in my question.

Comment: Better? Note that `ListDensityPlot` fails at sampling the edges and corners of the domains correcly. `VoronoiMesh` does much better which is why edges and corners appear sharper than in your plot.

Comment: Yes, it looks better.  But the shapes are having too much straight borders.  This is the issue.  My slow code could smooth the shapes and give curved borders, but it's very slow.

Comment: Hmm, the Rasterize may be a good trick, despite the ugly crude borders.  Try this in your code: **MedianFilter[Rasterize[M, ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}], 6]**

Comment: Hm. Maybe you are interested in shapes that arise during the Cahn-Hillard flow (see the animation in [my post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202459/38178))? This flow models two phases that slowly demix. Think of small grease drops on a soup (water) for example.

Comment: Wow!  The animation is very nice!!

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Syed:

In 0.264381 seconds on a Mac laptop:

```
ListContourPlot[RandomReal[1, {70, 70}], InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 Contours -> 1, ContourShading -> {Red, Purple}, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This method works, but apparently it gives many vertical and horizontal shapes.  It's not as "natural looking" as the slow method of my question.  We can feel a horizontal-vertical grid behind the structures.

Comment: @Cham:  I don't necessarily agree that it "gives many vertical and horizontal shapes";  it may just be that human brains are great at recognizing patterns, even when they don't exist.  You could test this out by creating an image "blindly", making a randomly rotated version, cropping the rotated version and the original, and seeing if you can tell the difference.

Comment: Also, I did try running Fourier analysis on this image file and didn't see any particular evidence of correlations along the axes vs. at angles to the vertices;  the transform looked pretty rotationally symmetric.

Comment: Yep.  I agree.............

Comment: Well, yet there's something wrong with the output.  There are some ugly artifacts and spikes...

Comment: Define "ugly."  Define "spikes."  And why weren't the clear, objective criteria for the visual features part of the problem statement?  What is this whole problem *about* anyway?

Comment: We don't need to define precisely what are "artifacts" and "spikes".  It's clearly visible to me.  Your output isn't of the same style as what I need, despite its strong ressemblance.  Henrik's answer is closer to what I need.

Comment: I've spent four decades in computer vision, art history, and have published on texture analysis (such as in Jackson Pollock's drip paintings), and given @MichaelSeifert's Fourier analysis, your "clearly visible to me" is vacuous.  But the central problem is that you still cannot define what you want, which is the dead giveaway of a poorly formulated question.